# GCC define function-like macros using -D argument

Tags: c, gcc, macros, command-line-arguments, c-preprocessor

**Problem**

I am trying to remove `__attribute__` from my **C** code before I send it into a parser. Is there a way to define function-like macros using the `-D` argument?

**Solution using header file**

```
#define __attribute__(x)
```

**Attempted Solution**

```
gcc -E -D__attribute__(x)= testfile.c
gcc -E -D__attribute__(x) testfile.c
```

Comment: Have you tried `gcc -E -D'__attribute__(x)' testfile.c` ? Your shell might interpret the parenthesis before sending the argument to `gcc`.

Comment: @NiBZ sorry that didn't worry. Came back saying "macro names must be identifiers"

Comment: Wierd, it worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04) ... (see https://gist.github.com/N-Bz/dff2706c2ccec97d9542 for what I tested). If the header file solution works, then maybe the `-include` option of `gcc` (force the inclusion of a header) might help you.

Comment: `gcc -E -D__attribute__(x)= testfile.c` works on windows.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

from the man pages

```
       If you wish to define a function-like macro on the command line,
       write its argument list with surrounding parentheses before the
       equals sign (if any).  Parentheses are meaningful to most shells,
       so you will need to quote the option.  With sh and csh,
       -D'name(args...)=definition' works.
```

So this works on a Unix/Linux shell

```
gcc -D'__attribute__(x)='
```

on Windows CMD the original expression works, since parentheses aren't special:

```
gcc -D__attribute__(x)=
```

Comment: Yeah, forgot the `=` in my previous comment. The `=` is needed because `-Dsomething` acts as `#define something 1`, not as `#define something`.

Comment: And if you have to pass it to a Makefile as a `CFLAGS=...` parameter, don't forget to quote twice, e.g. with `CFLAGS='"-D__attribute__(x)="'` (here I used double quotes inside single quotes to avoid escaping with `\ `).