# Define multiple-word macro using -D flag with gcc

Tags: c, shell, gcc, macros

The purpose of this is to build a program with command line-injected macros, using a Makefile.

I would like to define macros using multiple terms, however I am given an error as subsequent parts of the string are treated as files by `gcc`.

An example of what I need is as follows:

```c
#define ULL unsigned long long
#define T_ULL typedef unsigned long long ull_t
```

As a result, I am only able to create macros that contain 1 term per definition.

The latter attempt allows me to create parameterized macros, however those are also limited to 1 term per definition.

---

#### Attempted solution

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define _STRINGIZE(x)   #x
#define STRINGIZE(x)    _STRINGIZE(x)

int main(void)
{
#   ifdef DEBUG
    #   ifdef STRING
            printf("%s", "A STRING macro was defined.\n");
            printf("string: %s\n", STRINGIZE(STRING));
    #   else
            printf("%s\n", "A DEBUG macro was defined.");
    #   endif
#   endif
}
```

---

#### Results

As described by [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html), under the -D option description.

```sh
$ gcc define.c -D='DEBUG' ; ./a.out
A DEBUG macro was defined.
```

As described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31857844/8322076), as an alternative approach.

```sh
$ gcc define.c -D'DEBUG' ; ./a.out
A DEBUG macro was defined.
$ gcc define.c -D'DEBUG' -D'STRING="abc"' ; ./a.out
A STRING macro was defined.
string: "abc"
$ gcc define.c -D'DEBUG' -D'STRING="abc efg"' ; ./a.out
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'efg"'
A STRING macro was defined.
string: "abc"
$ gcc define.c -D'DEBUG' -D'STRING="abc efg hij"' ; ./a.out
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'efg'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'hij"'
A DEBUG macro was defined.
string: "abc"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `STRINGIZE` macro. The correct command-line syntax is:

```
gcc -DDEBUG -DSTRING='"abc def"' program.c
```

In other words, you need to quote the whole value of the defined macro, including C string delimiters (`"`).

Then you can just do:

```
printf("string: %s\n", STRING);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was also able to do `gcc program.c -D'DEBUG' -D'STRING="abc def"'` which works as well. For some reason, the string was being broken up by the shell.